# SwiftUI - Array default values when opening the view

Tags: swiftui

I have an array:

```
var customers: [Customer] = [
   Customer(name: "Arthur", sum: 143),
   Customer(name: "John", sum: 25)
]
```

Then I change the array by pressing a button:

```
customers[0].sum = 15
```

Then I close the view and open it again. The thing is that when I open my view for the second time I want to have default array values (**which for this case would be that Arthur sum is 143 and not the 15**).

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Would you show your view or demo code for this?

Comment: @Asperi repo: https://github.com/GustasCodes/Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ViewB: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var customers: [Customer] = [
        Customer(name: "Arthur", sum: 143),
        Customer(name: "John", sum: 25)
     ]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Close")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("sum: \(customers[0].sum)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                customers[0].sum = 15
            }) {
                Text("Change sum")
            }
        }.padding(.all, 15)
    }
}

struct ViewB_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewB()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually not a bad solution. But I'm pretty sure that my array is going to be a much more bigger than current one and then the code will not look clean. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer because at least it's now working. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I just found how to keep the code a little bit more clean with your answer! @State var customers: [Customer] = customersData and then I can keep the default values in customersData which can be in another .swift file